# RubyMotion (Android) - "uninitialized constant `Date'"

Tags: android, ruby, rubymotion

I'm new to RubyMotion and trying to use a Ruby Date object in an Android app and can't seem to get it to work. I've looked for Date examples/tutorials but can't find any.

In my Rakefile I have this:

```
require 'date'
```

Trying to just do something basic like:

```
today = Date.today
```

I get this error:

```
Exception raised: NameError: uninitialized constant `Date'
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a RubyMotion Android omission. I'd report it to HipByte via `motion support`.